# Logon form with checking row and password verify

Tags: php, hash

i have a logon form below but currently when i login with a valid username and any password from other username it will work. I'm trying to fix this flaw with if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==1)

I would need to point it to the row of the username and validate only with the hash password in the same row. Should I put it in the same condition as the password_verify ?

[image]

```
$username = trim ($username);
        $passWD = trim ($passWD);

        $loginerror = array();

        if (empty($username)) {
            $loginerror[] = "You have not entered all of the required fields";
        }
        elseif (strlen($username) < 8 OR strlen($username) > 30) {
        $loginerror[] = "Username is too short or too long";

        if (empty($passWD)) {
            $loginerror[] = "You have not entered all of the required fields";
        }
        elseif (strlen($passWD) < 8) {
            $loginerror[] = "You have not entered all of the required fields";
        } 

        if (!empty($loginerror))
        for ($a=0;$a<count($loginerror);$a++)
        {
        echo "$loginerror[$a] <br />\n";
        }
        else
        {

include 'database_conn.php';    // make db connection

                $sql = "SELECT username,passwordHash FROM users WHERE username = ? AND passwordHash =?";
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);    // prepare the sql statement

                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $passWD);     
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // execute the query

                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $passWDHash);

                if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) 
                    {
                    password_verify($passWD, $passWDHash);
                    echo "<p>Login successful</p>";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                    echo "<p>Sorry please try again.</p>";
                    }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); 
        mysqli_close($conn);
        }
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Do you have multiple usernames that are the same? This query should surely only return the row that you want. Add `LIMIT 1` if necessary.

Comment: Sorry I have a different error now after i added in the $loginerror array.. It seems all username will echo "Sorry please try again." Yes all username are different

Comment: Where do you do the password hash? In you example you pass to your sql query the password (which I'm guessing is not hashed) but you use as if it is hashed: "AND passwordHash = $passWD". Also, can we see the password_verify function? Finally, your loginerror messages are not too clear: you check the length of the username and if it does not match you say it should be alphanumeric; you check the length of the password and if it does not match you say a required field is empty - that might confuse the user.

Comment: The user sql is already provided, i just attached the table in the question. The password_verify function is in the question after the mysql_stmt statement. Thanks I change the error message for the length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rewrite your SQL statement, it is not possible to search for a salted hash in the database. Search only by username and afterwards check the found hash with `password_verify()` as you did:

```
$sql = "SELECT username,passwordHash FROM users WHERE username = ?";
...
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);

if (password_verify($passWD, $passWDHash))
{
  echo "<p>Login successful</p>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks ok but it seems even if i use a valid password from other users it also was able to login.

Comment: @DoranL - That's because you don't do anything with the result of password_verify(). This function returns a bool to tell whether the password matches or not, i edited the answer to show the problem.

Comment: oh i get it.. it's like i'm just telling it to echo "Login successfully" regardless of what login details was put in.